# Resources about how to develop a Java look and feel

Tags: java, user-interface

I'd like to learn more about developing a Java look and feel. Could anybody please give me some web adresses where i can find resources about laf development?

Thanks in advance,

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing a custom Look and Feel isn't your only option.  You may also choose to build upon the [Synth Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html), which is a framework for developing L&Fs upon.

[Nimbus](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/nimbus_laf.html) is a well known Synth-based L&F, and is included in the [OpenJDK 6 source code](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/) under `/jdk/src/share/classes/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/nimbus`

Answer (score 3):

- [How to Write a Custom Look and Feel](http://today.java.net/article/2006/09/11/how-write-custom-look-and-feel)
- [Creating a Custom Look and Feel](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/sce/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I tried Googling for you but found the pickings slim, as you probably did too.

An approach that doesn't require external resources would be to simply download the Java library source code (you may need to sign up as a developer with <s>Sun</s>Oracle) and then to make your own copy of everything with the changes you want.

I've known a group in our company who tried to develop a company specific look and feel. They made a lot of stupid mistakes, such as making the checkboxes and radio buttons have the same shape; that took away information from the user.

Doing your own L&F is a lot of hard work. Maybe the most useful advice I can give you is to review whether you or the world really, truly need yet another Java look and feel. How is yours going to be different? Better? Are you prepared to invest the work to really polish it? To provide all the icons and images, all the procedural rendering for every variation of every component?

Answer (score 1):

You can check my open source Look and Feel project - [WebLookAndFeel](http://weblookandfeel.com)
Most of the sources are properly commented in english so it won't be hard to understand the code :)

Comment: Thanks! Soon this project will exit its beta-state and will get first stable release and some proper documentation on the site - it might also help getting deep into the code later.

Answer (score 1):

Like Powerlord has said, I would suggest looking into the Synth class, more specifically at the [Java Tutorials on Customizing the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/)!. I have played with it myself and been able to produce a rather more appealing GUI, so I would say it is a powerful tool worth looking into. This is what I managed to come up with myself:

[image: News Feed Application with custom UI]

Answer (score 0):

You can download the "EaSynth Look And Feel Designer" on the official website. The complete version in payed, but in the free version, after each modification, the application shows(not in a explicity mode) how you can do the same thing in XML for Synth L&F.